# After update, grub is broken

Tags: boot, grub2, wubi

Some months back I used wubi to install ubuntu on an hp laptop with vista.  After not using it for a month or so, I loaded ubuntu and installed many updates (including kernel update).  Windows boot manager loads without any problems, and I can boot to vista without problems.  However, if I choose ubuntu, the screen briefly flashes

> Try (hd0,0) : NTFS5

and then goes to black.  I never get to the kernel image selection screen.

Comment: Post the results of http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/477104) is the bug report. You might try the solution offered by [comment 90](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/477104/comments/90)

All you need to do is download the file attached to the comment and replace your current C:\wubildr with it.

Also, of note from post 91:

> Please make sure that when you boot the line "insmod ntfs" is commented out or disable it by pressing "e" at the grub boot menu and edit the entry before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Is grub looking at the correct partition on the hard drive? you might want to use an installation cd and get it to repair the installation, maybe some of the updates edited the partition location in grub. Usually, windows likes to be 0,0. Try 0,1.